# regular expression for quotes and whitespaces

Tags: regex

I have this expression

```
("[^"]+")|(\s\S*\s)
```

which gets any characters that are in quotes and with white spaces around it.

Seems to work ok, but i was wondering if its possible to get just the characters inside the quotes and whitespaces.

I tried:
    `("[^"]+")|([^\s]\S*[^\s])`
but i am not sure how to do the same for quotes as it will mess it up if i try the same thing.

Sample

```
This is "a short" little sentence!
```

With the regex it should return

`This`
`is`
`a short`
`little`
`sentence!`

instead of
`_This_`
`_is_`
`"a short"`
`_little_`
`_sentence!_`

where _ = a space

There are spaces included before and after and the quotes are still there too.

Thanks.

Comment: Please include samples of what you get currently and what you ultimately want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a guess from your descriptions.

```
"([^"]+)"|\s(\S*)\s
```

Samples will produce better regex.

Comment: I would also change `\S*` to `\S+`. +1

Comment: So i got what i needed with grouping. Took your advice though and changed it.